# Get a geometry point along a line from another point with distance using OGC SFSQL

Tags: postgis, ogc

I am wondering is that any quick OGC SFSQL function (or any other spatial query) which return a geometry point that:

The point is x distance along a line from its A-End ?

ps: I am using postgis 2.x

Comment: http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Line_Interpolate_Point.html together with http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Length.html